# Based turn card game using Firebase and Kotlin: Storing and retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm creating a based turn card game using kotlin and firebase.

My problem is that each player can choose a character to play between Warrior, Mage, Healer, and Archer. The characters all have similar structures (hp, attack point, money and cards to draw) however they also have individual variables (for example the mage and healer have mana).
What I want to do is have a "Player" class containing an object "Character". this means having a "Character" class and 4 classes "Warrior", "Mage", "Healer" and "Archer" that inherit from it.

```
class Player constructor(uid: String?, name: String?): Serializable{

    var mUid: String? = ""
    var mName: String? = null
    var mCharacter: Character? = null
    var mHealth = 0
    var mAttack = 0
    var mMoney = 0

    init {
        mUid = uid
        mName = name
    }

    ...
}
```

```
abstract open class Character: Serializable {

    var mStartingMoney = 0
    var mStartingHealth = 0
    var mStartingAttack = 0

    abstract fun card1(listPlayer: HashMap<String, Player>?, currentPlayerUid: String?)
    abstract fun card2(listPlayer: HashMap<String, Player>?, currentPlayerUid: String?)
    abstract fun card3(listPlayer: HashMap<String, Player>?, currentPlayerUid: String?)

    fun playCard(i: Int, listPlayer: HashMap<String, Player>?, currentPlayerUid: String?) {
        when (i) {
            1   -> card1(listPlayer, currentPlayerUid)
            2   -> card2(listPlayer, currentPlayerUid)
            3   -> card3(listPlayer, currentPlayerUid)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

```
class Mage: Character() {

    var mStartingMana = 0

    init {
        mStartingHealth = 4
        mStartingAttack = 1
        mStartingMoney = 2
        mStartingMana = 3
    }

    override fun card1(listPlayer: HashMap<String, Player>?, currentPlayerUid: String?)
    {
        listPlayer!![currentPlayerUid]!!.addMana(2)
    }

    override fun card2(listPlayer: HashMap<String, Player>?, currentPlayerUid: String?)
    {
        listPlayer!![currentPlayerUid]!!.addMoney(2)
    }

    override fun card3(listPlayer: HashMap<String, Player>?, currentPlayerUid: String?)
    {
        listPlayer!![currentPlayerUid]!!.loseHealth(2)
    }

    ...
}
```

However, this seems to causes issues with Firebase when I try to retrieve the player's value. It will try to instantiate a Character, which isn't possible due to it being abstract. What I want is for Firebase to instantiate the right subtype of Character when it's reading the data, but it has no way of knowing what subtype it is. (cf Frank van Puffelen on [android firebase unable to instantiate abstract class when call getValue() in listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637159/android-firebase-unable-to-instantiate-abstract-class-when-call-getvalue-in-li)).

So if anyone has any suggestion on how I could make this work or on how I could manage my classes better I'll really appreciate! Thank you.

Comment: Which database are you using, Realtime Database or Firestore?  Also, please edit the question to show exactly the code that you're trying to use that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has no way to know which class to instantiate, so you'll have to build that part yourself. Typically this means storing a property about the character class in the database, and writing/reading that property before writing/reading the other properties of the character.

Then once you've read the character class from the database, you can instantiate the class in your code, and have it read the (other) properties.

So if you're using Realtime Database and have the path to the JSON of a character, that'd look something like this:

```
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference.child("path/to/character")
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object:ValueEventListener() {
  fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot:DataSnapshot) {
    val character:Char
    val characterClass = dataSnapshot.child("class").getValue(String::class.java)
    if ("Mage" == characterClass)
    {
      character = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mage::class.java)
    }
  }
  fun onCancelled(databaseError:DatabaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException()
  }
})
```

There's probably a more idiomatic way to do this in Kotlin, but this should be good enough to get you started.